# Why does this sql query error show up? Is there maybe another way to write this?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am using the [Chinook](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database) database for a project and I have two difficult queries to execute, but both provide errors.

1. I am looking for all the orders (invoice) that were sent to 'New York' and contain tracks that belong to more than one genre. [InvoiceId, amount of products, total1, total2]. Total1 should be unitprice*quantity and total2 is total. It should show only 2 rows.
   So far I have come up with this. I have also tried switching up with left join, full outer join, etc

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS
SELECT * 
FROM track join invoiceline USING (TrackId) 
WHERE (select * from track t1 where EXISTS (select * from track t2 where t1.GenreId <> t2.GenreId));

SELECT invoice.InvoiceId, invoiceline.Quantity, invoiceline.UnitPrice*invoiceline.Quantity, invoice.Total 
FROM (SELECT * FROM invoice JOIN invoiceline 
WHERE invoice.BillingCity LIKE '%New York%') JOIN temp cc ON invoiceline.TrackId
GROUP BY invoiceline.InvoiceId;

DROP TABLE temp;
```

It provides the error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

2. I am looking for clients (in couples) that have bought more than two of the same tracks. It should provide 14 rows.
   Until now I have come up with this.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,',', LASTNAME) AS name1 FROM customer
JOIN invoice ON customer.CustomerId = invoice.CustomerId
JOIN invoiceline ON invoice.InvoiceId = invoiceline.InvoiceId
JOIN track ON invoiceline.TrackId = track.TrackId
UNION
(
SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,',', LASTNAME) AS name2 FROM customer
JOIN invoice ON customer.CustomerId = invoice.CustomerId
JOIN invoiceline ON invoice.InvoiceId = invoiceline.InvoiceId
JOIN track ON invoiceline.TrackId = track.TrackId
);
```

So A) Does anybody know why it provides that error?
B) Could anyone give any tips or suggest a better way to write these queries?

Here are two helpful schemas:[ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv0x8.png)
[relational diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWXCf.png)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this condition: `WHERE (select * from track t1 where EXISTS (select * from track t2 where t1.GenreId <> t2.GenreId))`? this is what leads to the error.

Comment: I wanted to check if there is at least a couple of tracks with different Genre Ids, from the same order.

Comment: *I am looking for clients (in couples) that have bought more than two of the same tracks.* You must count the amount of purchases per user and track. GROUP BY, COUNT, HAVING. 1st exercise needs in GROUP BY too.

Comment: Please share some sample data.

Comment: There is an explicit close reason for questions containing multiple questions. Pls ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to you first question:
The error comes up because many rows would have a single genre id. This method is also very redundant.
You should use count of genre Ids and take track Ids with count more than 1 as shown below:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS
SELECT * 
FROM track join invoiceline USING (TrackId) 
WHERE TrackId in 
(select TrackId from (select TrackId, count(distinct GenreId) as genres from track group by 1 having genres>1));

SELECT invoice.InvoiceId, invoiceline.Quantity, invoiceline.UnitPrice*invoiceline.Quantity, invoice.Total 
FROM (SELECT * FROM invoice JOIN invoiceline 
WHERE invoice.BillingCity LIKE '%New York%') JOIN temp cc ON invoiceline.TrackId
GROUP BY invoiceline.InvoiceId;

DROP TABLE temp;
```

I have assumed that track id is the primary key here.

For the second question, I assume that you want to find customers buying the same records. You can use a query like the one below:

```
SELECT invoiceline.TrackId, group_concat(customer.CustomerId) as customers FROM customer
JOIN invoice ON customer.CustomerId = invoice.CustomerId
JOIN invoiceline ON invoice.InvoiceId = invoiceline.InvoiceId
JOIN track ON invoiceline.TrackId = track.TrackId
group by 1
```

This will give you comma separated customer ids who have bought the same track. Also, use customer id instead of first name and last name since some customers can have the same name. Using primary key is best.

Since you mentioned, you want customers buying the same records in couples, I would suggest reading up on market basket analysis or association analysis using apriori algorithm. You can import your dataset into R or Python whichever you are comfortable with and build a visualization. Python is faster and can handle more data but its visualizations are bad. R is a bit slow at handling large amounts of data but has good visualizations for apriori algorithm

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Thank you though for trying, it was helpful! I have the whole database linked in the first line and have added two schemas if there are of any help!

Comment: @Stella what is the error you get when trying count?